# Not sure how to deploy web application running on web socket server using Heroku

Tags: html, node.js, heroku, websocket

I am a beginner with both Node and Heroku and have made a website that populates itself using data from a web socket server. The program has 2 files, server.js which creates all the data and index.html which handles the data received from the web socket and also contains the code for the website. The code works locally.

My main issue is knowing whether or not index.html is being run by heroku when i open the app, since the website that pops up is black and has the message "Upgrade required". It does not have the globe that the index.html file should be making. I have accessed the logs and there seems to be no indication that the client is connecting either, and even the port literals seemed to be not right as earlier in the log it prints $PORT but then it inputs a number but in either case the client connect message isnt showing so clearly the requests arent being received. I have provided the log messages here.

LOG

```
2024-02-29T20:33:13.681568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2024-02-29T20:33:15.152665+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T20:33:15.152672+00:00 app[web.1]: > start
2024-02-29T20:33:15.152673+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2024-02-29T20:33:15.152673+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T20:33:15.196664+00:00 app[web.1]: WebSocket server is listening on port ${PORT}
2024-02-29T20:33:15.686337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-02-29T20:33:31.889699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=5b6b8100-317a-4b18-8e17-dfbb21e7932f fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=3ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T20:33:32.186523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=5c420468-0553-431e-a517-34a49fc03221 fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T20:40:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user r
2024-02-29T20:40:32.761526+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9919da47 by user r
2024-02-29T20:40:32.761526+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user r
2024-02-29T20:40:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-02-29T20:40:36.583188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2024-02-29T20:40:36.630499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-02-29T20:40:37.337512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-02-29T20:40:37.415937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2024-02-29T20:40:40.805956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2024-02-29T20:40:42.261455+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T20:40:42.261461+00:00 app[web.1]: > start
2024-02-29T20:40:42.261461+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2024-02-29T20:40:42.261461+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T20:40:42.306493+00:00 app[web.1]: WebSocket server is listening on port ${PORT}
2024-02-29T20:40:42.771717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-02-29T20:40:44.287078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=e9fd4f8a-9ae6-4683-84fe-d672cb4a9a59 fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T20:40:44.587029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=8398b00b-f791-451b-aad7-0196b91ed768 fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T21:01:42.817007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=7e45e46e-7410-48a1-b00f-d1792f54b409 fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T21:01:43.151086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=b7e0a4bc-db20-43b2-b6f9-256ab4959e30 fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T21:04:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user r
2024-02-29T21:04:45.990062+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user r
2024-02-29T21:04:45.990062+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a7a67f86 by user r
2024-02-29T21:04:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-02-29T21:04:46.373938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2024-02-29T21:04:46.423301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-02-29T21:04:47.110103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-02-29T21:04:47.193012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2024-02-29T21:04:51.259370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2024-02-29T21:04:52.842195+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T21:04:52.842258+00:00 app[web.1]: > start
2024-02-29T21:04:52.842258+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2024-02-29T21:04:52.842259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-29T21:04:52.890270+00:00 app[web.1]: WebSocket server is listening on port 31909
2024-02-29T21:04:53.288654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-02-29T21:06:35.800931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=ee8367d3-c142-45a3-909f-20b2565692bf fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
2024-02-29T21:06:36.102211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-sands-49739-625be7f06e14.herokuapp.com request_id=9b3327b8-d25d-4d0b-ade1-feacbdb69e0b fwd="223.190.84.15" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=426 bytes=151 protocol=https
```

Here's also my code:

server.js

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = new WebSocket.Server({port: PORT});

server.on("listening", () =\> {
console.log(`WebSocket server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

server.on("connection", ws =\> {
console.log("Client connected!");

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
       const unlockEvent = generateUnlockEvent();
       ws.send(unlockEvent);

}, 200);

    ws.on('close', () => {
       console.log('Client disconnected!');
       clearInterval(interval);
       ws.close(function () {
        console.log('Server closed! ');
      });

});
});
```

index.html
(just provided the part of the code that should handle the web socket, the prior code is taken from a framework and essentially emulates a globe... it works)

```
const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 3000;

    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`);
    
    ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
      console.log("Connected!")
    
      ws.addEventListener("message", event => {
        const newData = JSON.parse(event.data)
        counting++
        updateGlobe(newData)
        updateTable(newData)
      })
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        updateDisplay();
        setInterval(updateDisplay, 15000);
      }, 15000);
    
    })
```

I feel I should be editing package.json or the port to get it to work, I don't see why the website doesnt show up at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9sgR.png)

Honestly I have tried to fix this issue for days and this is my 2nd repo. I tried a few things including the Procfile and that's also how I reached 0.0.0.0 or using the process.env.PORT variable but the errors got so complicated I started over.